# Flex: Change line height of Label component

Tags: apache-flex, label

Maybe I'm googling for the wrong thing but I can't find anything on this.

How can I change the line height of a Label element in Flex?

I have two labels in a VBox and there is quite a lot of white space between them which I would like to reduce. There's no line height property and setting the height property causes overlap.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Cheers,

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about changing the VBox padding and gap?

```
<mx:VBox x="380" y="301" width="100%" height="100%" verticalGap="0" paddingBottom="0" paddingTop="0">
    <mx:Label text="Label"/>
    <mx:Label text="Label"/>
</mx:VBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the lineHeight style on the Label. See the reference on Label class [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/Label.html).